# Why the list rule is strange in the Cloud?

Tags: list-manipulation, wolfram-cloud

If we have some data,for example:

```
data = Table[{i, i + 1, i + 2}, {i, 10, 80, 10}];
data[[All, 1]]
Export["test.xls", %%]
```

the output is:

> {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80}

As we can take the first column easily.

But the situation is difficult to understand in the Wolfram Cloud:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"file" -> "XLS"}, #file[[All, 1]]&],Permissions ->"Public" ]
```

the output is:

> https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/2335f4c8-9410-4075-8881-ef7f573123a8

if I upload the test.xls,it outputs the first row:

> {{10,11,12}}

What's the wrong in the Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing strange happened in the cloud. The same thing happens when you carry out your operation locally.

```
data = Table[{i, i + 1, i + 2}, {i, 10, 80, 10}]
```

> ```
> {{10, 11, 12}, {20, 21, 22}, {30, 31, 32}, {40, 41, 42}, 
>  {50, 51, 52}, {60, 61, 62}, {70, 71, 72}, {80, 81, 82}}
> ```

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.xls"}], data];
xls = Import[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.xls"}]]
```

> ```
> {{{10., 11., 12.}, {20., 21., 22.}, {30., 31., 32.}, {40., 41., 42.}, 
>   {50., 51., 52.}, {60., 61., 62.}, {70., 71., 72.}, {80., 81.,82.}}}
> ```

Note the extra `List` wrapper in the imported data. So naturally

```
xls[[All, 1]]
```

gives

> `{{10., 11., 12.}}`

You want

```
xls[[1, All, 1]]
```

> `{10., 20., 30., 40., 50., 60., 70., 80.}`

Comment: briefly explain! it is really a secret mechanism.Thank you a lot :)

Comment: You get one list of lists *for every sheet in the Excel file* even if there is only one. So you have lists three levels deep.